# Can I reuse SQL or use some type of dynamic join for this stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a `GetUsers` stored procedure as shown below. If a `@GroupId` or `@GroupName` parameter is provided, then I need to beef up the stored procedure to ensure that only users belonging to a matching group are returned.

I've created a special table variable named `@GroupUserMatches` which contains a `UserId`/`GroupId` association for matching user groups. I could essentially copy/paste the SQL from the ELSE block into the IF block and update it a bit to accommodate a join to `@GroupUserMatches`, but I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to do this?

One concern is that I'd like to avoid having to make updates to the same SQL select in 2 different blocks in the same stored procedure. If no `@GroupId` or `@GroupName` are provided, then the user list returned should be completely unfiltered by group.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetUsers]
    @DomainId uniqueidentifier = NULL,
    @DomainName varchar(100) = NULL,
    @NetworkUserId varchar(100) = NULL,
    @UserPrincipalName varchar(100) = NULL,
    @FirstName varchar(100) = NULL,
    @LastName varchar(100) = NULL,
    @EmailAddress varchar(255) = NULL,
    @GroupId uniqueidentifier = NULL,
    @GroupName varchar(500) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @GroupUserMatches TABLE
    (
        GroupId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, 
        UserId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
    )

    IF(@GroupId IS NOT NULL OR @GroupName IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @GroupUserMatches (GroupId, UserId)
            SELECT geue.GroupExtensionId, geue.UserExtensionId
            FROM ADGroup adg 
            JOIN GroupExtension ge ON adg.Id = ge.ADGroupId
            JOIN GroupExtensionUserExtension geue ON ge.Id = geue.GroupExtensionId
            WHERE (@GroupId IS NULL OR ge.Id = @GroupId) 
              AND (@GroupName IS NULL OR adg.[Name] LIKE @GroupName + '%')
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT 
            au.*,
            0 HasExtendedSecurity
        FROM 
            AllUsers au
        JOIN 
            Domain d ON au.DomainName = d.[Name]
        WHERE 
            (@DomainId IS NULL OR au.DomainId = @DomainId) AND
            (@DomainName IS NULL OR au.DomainName = @DomainName) AND
            (@NetworkUserId IS NULL OR au.NetworkUserId = @NetworkUserId) AND
            (@UserPrincipalName IS NULL OR au.UserPrincipalName = @UserPrincipalName) AND
            (@FirstName IS NULL OR au.FirstName LIKE @FirstName + '%') AND
            (@LastName IS NULL OR au.LastName LIKE @LastName + '%' ) AND 
            (@EmailAddress IS NULL OR au.Email LIKE @EmailAddress + '%') 
    END
END
```

Comment: You have two potentially major performance challenges here. You have a catch all query which can be very problematic. You also have multiple execution paths. Gail Shaw has a great article on both of these topics and ways to solve it. https://www.sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/ and https://www.sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/09/15/multiple-execution-paths/

Comment: Question is not clear to me

Comment: You can just `join` the `select`s together and handle the NULL `@GroupId` and `@GroupName` conditions in the appropriate `on` clauses. (Or use `outer join`s and the `where` clause.) That said, Dr. Lange is right about the kvetch-all query being an issue that would only get worse.